# Graph theory and Combinatorics - how many walks?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, random-walk

The question is more combinatorial, but it is based on graph theory.

**How many walks with length $k$ does an $r$-regular graph with $n$ nodes contain?**

Well $r$-*regular* means that all nodes have $r$ neighbours, but how to determine the number of walks... I have found that $n^{\underline k}$, $n = $ number of nodes, $k = $ nodes in the walk, is one plausible formula for that purpose, but still I can`t put in $r$.

Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: Are there any assumptions on the graph these walks are within, e.g. is it complete?

Comment: @muaddib: The assumption is that it’s $r$-regular.

Comment: Why is there an underline under the k in your exponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $n$ choices of starting node. You then take $k-1$ steps, and at each step you have a choice of $r$ different neighboring nodes. Thus, the number of walks is $nr^{k-1}$.

Comment: what if you're not allowed to use the same edge twice?